# Не работает return в php

Tags: php, axios

подскажите почему не работает return в php ?

Есть php файл с следующим кодом

```
<?
$date = array(
    'client_id' => 123,
    'sender_id' => 253,
    'order_id'  => 666,
);

return $date;
?>
```

Обращаюсь к нему из другого файла запросом через axios, в ответе ничего не получаю, но если изменить на `print($date);` то успешно выводится массив

Что не так я делаю ?

Comment: а с чего ты решил что return должен что-то выводить?

Comment: И зачем обращаться из другого файла "через axios", если можно просто заинклюдить?

Comment: как мне вернуть в ответ этот массив в формате json ?

Comment: echo json_encode( $data );

Answer (score 2):

`return` - это конструкция, которая возвращает значение функции, но никак не выводит текст на экран.

Если Вы инклудите скрипт, то здесь даже никакой `return`, `print` или `echo` не нужен

А вообще вот как было бы правильно:

```
function getDate()
{
    $date = array(
        'client_id' => 123,
        'sender_id' => 253,
        'order_id'  => 666,
    );

    return $date;
}
```

и затем, например `$date = getDate();`